# Change key icon keyboard: Drawable return int?

Tags: android, keyboard, icons, key, drawable

I'm trying to change a key icon on press in run time:

```
@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    Keyboard currentKeyboard = KbView.getKeyboard();
    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = currentKeyboard.getKeys();
    KbView.invalidateKey(primaryCode);
    keys.get(primaryCode).label = null;
    keys.get(primaryCode).icon = R.drawable.image;
}
```

However, the last line says:

```
Incompatible types. 
Required: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 
Found: int
```

If I use instead: `keys.get(ponto).icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);`
says that getDrawable(int) is deprecated.
(It works, but when I press a key, change the icon  of other key)

(I'm using API level 8)

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem. Try this:

```
Keys.get(primaryCode).icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context, R.drawable.image);
```

You need to have the support lib in your project.